# Learning to use compareTo

Tags: java

Hi Guys I'm learning or trying to learn how to use compareTo().. I have a simple class which implements it but in the reverse order I'd like to can someone please point the obvious out to me as i seem to keep missing it. How do i reverse this.
Here is my simple example.

```
import java.util.*;

    public class H283
    {
      public static void main(String args[])
      {
        Task[] tasks = new Task[4];
        tasks[0] = new Task("Homework");
        tasks[0].setPriority(7);
        tasks[1] = new Task("Eat lunch");
        tasks[1].setPriority(Priority.MIN_PRIORITY);
        tasks[2] = new Task("Attend class");
        tasks[2].setPriority(Priority.MAX_PRIORITY);
        tasks[3] = new Task("Ned's project");
        tasks[3].setPriority(4);
        Arrays.sort(tasks);
        System.out.println("\n  TO-DO\n---------");
        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++)
          System.out.println(tasks[i].getName() + " \tpriority: " + tasks[i].getPriority());

      }
    }

    interface Priority
    {
      static final int MED_PRIORITY = 5;
      static final int MAX_PRIORITY = 10;
      static final int MIN_PRIORITY = 1;

      //-----------------------------------------------------------------
      //  Sets the object's priority level.
      //-----------------------------------------------------------------
      public void setPriority (int value);

      //-----------------------------------------------------------------
      //  Returns the object's priority level.
      //-----------------------------------------------------------------
      public int getPriority();
    }

    class Task implements Priority, Comparable<Task>
    {
      String name;
      private int priority;

      //-----------------------------------------------------------------
      //  Sets up this task with a medium priority level.
      //-----------------------------------------------------------------
      public Task (String taskName)
      {
        name = taskName;
        priority = MED_PRIORITY;
      }

      //-----------------------------------------------------------------
      // Returns this task's name.
      //-----------------------------------------------------------------
      String getName()
      {
        return name;
      }

      //-----------------------------------------------------------------
      //  Sets this task's priority level.
      //-----------------------------------------------------------------
      public void setPriority (int value)
      {
        priority = value;
      }

      //-----------------------------------------------------------------
      //  Returns this task's priority level.
      //-----------------------------------------------------------------
      public int getPriority()
      {
        return priority;
      }


      public int compareTo( Task other )
      {
//here is where i'd like to reverse the order


 int thePriority = getPriority()-other.getPriority();
    if ( thePriority != 0 )
      return thePriority;
    else
      return getPriority()-other.getPriority();
  }


}
```

Any advice would be awesome ... thank you

Comment: Reverse the order of what?

Comment: You could both simplify and reverse the order by reducing `compareTo` to a single line: `return other.getPriority() - getPriority()`

Comment: Thank you.. very simple great advice.

Comment: @neuronaut there is the problem that for corner case values this may return the wrong result; there is, however, `Integer.compare()`, so you really want to do `return Integer.compare(priority, other.priority)`.

Comment: @fge That is certainly safer if the priority values could become very large or small. However, I took a simple approach which more clearly demonstrates `compareTo` (since that's the OP's concern) rather than worrying about the intricacies of integer arithmetic for very large/small values in Java.

Comment: You should avoid using `x - y` to determine result of `compareTo` since it is easy to forget about scenario where `x` can be negative and `y` big enough to overflow integer and return positive value instead of negative one. It is safer to use `Integer.compare(x,y)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int compareTo( Task other ) {
    //here is where i'd like to reverse the order
    // Simply reverse the order of your subtraction
    int thePriority = other.getPriority()-getPriority();
        if ( thePriority != 0 )
           return thePriority;
        else
           return getPriority()-other.getPriority();
}
```

Just reversing the order of subtraction is one option. Or you can actually keep exactly what you have and just negate it.

```
public int compareTo( Task other ) {
    //here is where i'd like to reverse the order
    int thePriority = getPriority()-other.getPriority();
        if ( thePriority != 0 )
           return -thePriority; // Return negated priority
        else
           return getPriority()-other.getPriority();
}
```

Also your else statement is currently returning the exact same thing as your if. Unless you want to handle some other way of ordering equally prioritized Tasks (for example, ordering by name), then you can just as easily leave off the entire if/else statement and have your compareTo() method be one line.

```
public int compareTo( Task other ) { // Clean and simple!
    return -(getPriority()-other.getPriority());
}
```

In this case, you're not so much learning about compareTo() as you are implementing your own compareTo(). So you can make it return whatever you like.